# How to construct Markov kernels into a product measurable space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, product-measure

Let $(A,\mathcal E_A)$, $(B,\mathcal E_B)$, $(C,\mathcal E_C)$ be
measurable spaces. Let $f$ be a Markov kernel from $(A,\mathcal
E_A)$ to $(B,\mathcal E_B)$. Let $g$ be a Markov kernel from
$(A,\mathcal E_A)$ to $(C,\mathcal E_C)$.

Let $h_a$ be the unique
measure on $(B\times C,\mathcal E_B\otimes\mathcal E_C)$ such
that
$$h_a(E_B\times E_C) = f(a,E_B)\cdot g(a,E_C)$$
for all $E_B\in\mathcal E_B$, $E_C\in\mathcal E_C$.

If we write $h(a,E)=h_a(E)$, then is $h$ a Markov kernel from $(A,\mathcal E_A)$ to $(B\times C,\mathcal E_B\otimes\mathcal E_C)$? In
particular, is the map $a\mapsto h_a(E)$ a real-valued measurable function for all
$E\in\mathcal B\otimes\mathcal C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the map $a\mapsto h_a(E)$ is $\mathcal E_A$-measurable for each $E\in\mathcal E_B\otimes\mathcal E_C$. The proof of this is a nice exercise in the use of Dynkin's form of the Monotone Class Theorem. The collection $\mathcal R:=\{E_B\times E_C: E_B\in\mathcal E_B, E_C\in\mathcal E_C\}$ of ''rectangles'' is a $\pi$-system generating $\mathcal E_B\otimes\mathcal E_C$. You check that the collection $\mathcal G:=\{E\in \mathcal E_B\otimes\mathcal E_C:a\mapsto h_a(E)$ is $\mathcal E_A$-measurable$\}$ is a $\lambda$-system (containing $\mathcal R$). Therefore $\mathcal G=\sigma(\mathcal R)=\mathcal E_B\otimes\mathcal E_C$.

Comment: If $(\Omega_i, \mathcal A_i)$ are measurable spaces for $i=1,2$, suppose $\kappa : \Omega_1 \times \mathcal A_2 \to [0,\infty] $ has the property that $\omega_1 \mapsto \kappa(\omega_1, A_2)$ is $\mathcal A_1$-measurable for every $A_2$ in a $\pi$-system containing $\Omega_2$. Can we say that the analogous collection $\mathcal G :=\{ A \in \mathcal A_2 : \omega_1 \mapsto \kappa(\omega_1, A_2) \textrm{ is $\mathcal A_1$-measurable}\}$ is a $\lambda$-system? My prob theory reference says yes but I think I have a counterexample when $\kappa(\omega_1, \cdot)$ isn't a measure on $\mathcal A_2$.

Comment: (Correction: a $\pi$-system containing $\Omega_2$ and whose generated $\sigma$-algebra is $\mathcal A_2$.)